# What definition do you give these algebraic structures of "unmapped" (sorry for unrigorous definition) functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, vector-spaces, differential-forms, jacobian

I know a bit of abstract algebra and of things like group theory. However, I know little beyond the very basic examples of the field. Forgive me for the lack of rigor or precise definition in what I describe, for I am only describing things as I see them, without understanding the proper language or definitions.

I've been studying differential forms and vector spaces of linear functions, but am having trouble understanding rigorously certain details. Let me give a concrete example of what may concern me. Take a Jacobian of form:

$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
{\partial f \over \partial x}(a) & {\partial f \over \partial y}(a) \\
{\partial f \over \partial x}(b) & {\partial f \over \partial x}(b) \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
{\partial f \over \partial x} & {\partial f \over \partial y}\\
{\partial f \over \partial x} & {\partial f \over \partial x} \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot \left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
{a} \\
{b} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I am most confused on this specific array:
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
{\partial f \over \partial x} & {\partial f \over \partial y}\\
{\partial f \over \partial x} & {\partial f \over \partial x} \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
It appears as if these functions are almost "floating" without being defined on any domain (not even the real number line or some $x$. Although sin($a$) and cos($a$) are not linear operators, it seems a bit to me like writing "multiplication" of the form:

$$ \mathrm{sin}(a) + \mathrm{cos}(a) = (\mathrm{sin} + \mathrm{cos})(a) $$
Where sin and cos seem to be "floating" without any map to a domain, and $a$ is some real number. If you continue to write "multiplication" out you could get something like:
$$ (b) (\mathrm{sin} + \mathrm{cos}) (a) = b \cdot\mathrm{sin}(a) + b \cdot\mathrm{cos}(a) \neq a \cdot\mathrm{sin}(b) + a \cdot\mathrm{cos}(b) = (a) (\mathrm{sin} + \mathrm{cos}) (b)$$
In this case if you "multiply" from the left side, these "floating" sin and cos values behave like vectors, and the left-handed multiplication behaves like scalar multiplication of a vector. But if you "multiply" from the right side, you are performing the mapping of the function to some real-numbered value. I'm wondering what these "floating" functions are called professionally, and what this algebraic structure is. I believe that the left-handed multiplication does in fact satisfy a vector space, but this definition of right-handed multiplication seems to add a bit of extra structure, and defines "something" else. Any recommendations for further reading would be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of further reading you can do in multivariable calculus, linear algebra, differential forms, etc. But don't be surprised if your questions are never answered for you; they are a little too vague and do not have a good match with any specific rigorous notations or definitions. One can certainly study  [function spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space) which are vector spaces whose individual elements are functions; but this is only done with a fixed choice of domain and range, and fixed choice of functions. A "floating function", as you express it, is not a "thing".

Comment: Even in the example you gave there was a definition of $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. Since it is listed as a separate component of the product, I would be interested in knowing what the $(f + g)$ component is called rigorously.

Comment: It is called the sum of the functions $f$ and $g$. That binary operator $+$ in the expression $f+g$ is the operation of taking the sum of two functions that have the same domain and range. Since $f+g$ is a function, it has a value assigned for every $x$ in the domain, and the definition of that value is $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$. That's what it means in a high-powered functional analysis book, and that's what it means in an ordinary undergraduate precalculus book.

Comment: Much appreciated. The confusion came from the way that differential forms are used. I've seen functions of some form (*dx), but from what I understood (dx) is itself a function that needs to be mapped to some domain. However, I've seen the domain not be written out for these differential forms.

Comment: Then it sounds like your post is an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): If what you really want is to understand differential forms, then that's what you should ask about, instead of something about "floating functions".